# How do I display a newline in a mysql prompt?

Tags: command-line, mysql, prompt

I'm trying to make my mysql prompt look like this:

```
root@localhost:3306 database
$ [mysql commands…]
```

How might I place the dollar sign on a newline?
Here's my current prompt configuration, in which the '\n' seems to be broken:

```
prompt = '\u@\h:\p\s\d\n$\s'
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. It appears that you have the dollar sign on a line of its own.

Comment: I should have clarified: the \n in my prompt string does not move the dollar sign to a new line.

Comment: Tried with mysql 5.0.51, both specified in the monitor (i.e. `prompt \u@\h:\p\s\d\n$\s`) and in `~/.my.cnf` (`prompt = '\u@\h:\p\s\d\n$\s'`), and had no trouble either way. What version of MySQL are you trying this against, and how are you passing it the prompt string?

Comment: @AaronMiller I just tried the same, but the `$` doesn't appear on a newline either. My version is: `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.17, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`

Comment: @CMCDragonkai Try a version compiled with readline instead of editline; I've never used a client built with the latter, and never had trouble with `\n` in a client built with the former.